# Select distinct items by combination of two columns and where Value of third column is max- LINQ

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, linq

My Object structure is like this

```
public class ProductToBids
{

    public int BidAmount { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BidDate { get; set; }
    public int BiddedUserId { get; set; }
    public string BidderEmail { get; set; }
    public string bidderName { get; set; }
    public int BidStatus { get; set; }
    public int FairId { get; set; }
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a list of this object like this

```
List<ProductToBids> productsInThisFairs = new List<ProductToBids>();
productsInThisFairs = FillData();
```

Now I want to select all rows from this list where combination of `BiddedUserId` and `ProductId` is unique, and if there is multiple rows satisfying this condition I want to select only the row which have the highest value in column `BidAmount` How can I achieve this?
I have tried doing this by Grouping the items first by two columns and taking max value later Code was like this

```
productsInThisFairs.DistinctBy(x=>new {x.ProductId,x.BiddedUserId }).ToList()
```

but understood that this will return only those two columns in the list all other columns will be discarded. Can anyone please point out what will be the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try a group by of your list items based on their `ProductId` and `BidderUserId` and then for each group to pick up the record with the highest `BidAmount`. The latter can be done by ordering the group items in a descending order based on their `BidAmount` and then pick the first item of each group.

```
var result = productsInThisFairs.GroupBy(prd=>new { prd.ProductId, prd.BiddedUserId})
                                .Select(grp => grp.OrderByDescending(item=>item.BidAmount)
                                                  .FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: throws an error like this
A local variable named 'grp' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'grp', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

Comment: @Athul My bad :(...Sorry...I just corrected it. Please check my update.